# Cypress.io compatible with Prometheus?

Tags: automated-tests, prometheus, cypress

We would probably use Cypress.io together with Prometheus.
Cypress makes a very good impression as a testing framework for end-to-end tests.
However we ask ourselves whether we will be able to easily connect Cypress with Prometheus so that the metrics find their way to the On-the-Wall-Dashboard.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Are you asking if you can use Cypress to measure the time it takes to perform a single test?

Comment: @ZachBloomquist I guess Cypress can measure the time to login... However I a unsure wether I can get the result into Prometheus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually this is possible. Use [Cypress.io's logging ability](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/log.html) and Prometheus's caching concept to provide a consistent data source when the Prometheus process scraps for data. Then in Graphana (an example only, other dashboard systems work as well) display the count, aggregate, time series data as desired.

My question, the same as @Zach and @Marc, is what data are you trying to display? Page load times? animation execution times? Test pass / fail? But again, conceptually it would be possible.

Comment: Mainly Tests pass/fail... but also execution times and everything that might be interesting from a DevOps perspective.

Answer (score -1):

Use for receive test result pass ot fail: `Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest;`
for getting running time:

```
 Cypress.on('test:after:run', (attributes) => {
  console.log('Test "%s" has finished in %dms',
    attributes.title, attributes.duration)
})
```